# Signing key error while upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, gnupg

I got this gpg error while upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04:

```
GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the key to the system using this command:

```sh
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

If not working yet, you can checkout [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey?rq=1)

OR

Re-signing the key with this commands:

```sh
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg
```

Reference: [VSCode Installation on Debian and Ubuntu based distributions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#:%7E:text=sudo%20apt%2Dget%20install%20wget,rm%20%2Df%20packages.microsoft.gpg)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but getting no change.karthik@karthik-Z590-UD-AC:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nNq5RnPtvY/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
gpg: key EB3E94ADBE1229CF: "Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

Comment: @karthikVijeyaraghavan Yes, sometimes it won't work. I just added another solution.